# How to prove something on limit points...

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$X = \mathbb R^n$. How to prove that the interior point of a subset of $X$ is also limit point?
Don't know where to start... by definition, an interior point is such if it **exists an** e-neighborhood such that it is included in the set.
Limit points in the other hand are such that **every** neighborhood will contain a point of the set. 
What's so special about $\mathbb R^n$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be an interior point of $X$. Since $a$ is an interior point of $X$ there is a neighborhood $A$ of $a$ such that $a \in A \subset X$. This shows that $a \in X$. Now let $B$ be any neighborhood of $a$. Then $a \in B \cap X$ and since $a \in X$ any neighborhood of $a$ contains a point in $X$. Thus $a$ is a limit point of $X$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this proof is not quite correct to me. The definition of limit point is: $a$ is the limit point of $X$, iff every neighbourhood of $a$ contains a point of $X$ OTHER THAN $a$, itself.

Comment: I also don't understand this answer. I fail to see where you use the fact that underlying space is $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (which is important).

Answer (score 1):

As $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a first countable topological space, you can reason on sequences; let $x \in Y \subset X$, by definition of interior point you get the existence of an $ \epsilon >0$ such that $ \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(x) \subset Y$ (Y is the subset of which x is an interior point). It's clear that each ball with same center and smaller radius is included in Y, thus you easily get a sequence that converges to x by picking an element in $ \mathcal{B}_{\frac{\epsilon}{n}}(x) \subset Y$. By definition of the metric topology, each neighborhood of x has to contain one of that ball and so one of that points, of course each of which is different from x.